# Does ifelse() perform type conversion?

Tags: r, lubridate

When adding 1 day to a date I get different results when performing the calculation directly and when performing it in a clause of an ifelse():

```
> x1 = ymd(maxDate)+days(1)
> x2 = ifelse(is.na(maxDate), "1800-01-01", ymd(maxDate)+days(1))

> maxDate
[1] "2020-11-24"
> x1
[1] "2020-11-25"
> x2
[1] 18591

> class(x1)
[1] "Date"
> class(x2)
[1] "numeric"
> class(maxDate)
[1] "character"
```

It looks like ifelse() will pass back maxDate as a character string, but if I convert it to a date with ymd() then it converts it from a Date to a numeric:

```
> ifelse(is.na(maxDate), "1800-01-01", maxDate)
[1] "2020-11-24"
> ifelse(is.na(maxDate), "1800-01-01", ymd(maxDate))
[1] 18590
> ymd(maxDate)
[1] "2020-11-24"
> d = ymd(maxDate)
> class(d)
[1] "Date"
```

I notice that if I manually convert it back to a character in the else as is well again:

```
> ifelse(is.na(maxDate), "1800-01-01", as.character(ymd(maxDate)+days(1)))
[1] "2020-11-25"
```

I'd very much like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: `ifelse` silently drops the `class` of an object. Unfortunately, this is both known and unlikely to change. If you are using the tidyverse (suggested by `ymd`), then use `dplyr::if_else`; another is `data.table::fifelse`; both are type-safe.

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans, pointers much appreciated.